# JS - (without jQuery) : regexp metadata

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find and replace a string within a classname.
I'm using a function wich returns me the "metadata" of a class:

e.g:

```
class="atestclass {action : '/myurl/param1/param2'}"
```

So the function metadata.action would return me "/myurl/param1/param2".

Now i need to change this value with regexp in a generic way.

So this is my RegExp and of course it dont work :(

```
var regExp = new RegExp(opts.attribute + '\'.\'','igm');
```

"opts.attribute" is in this case "action". Now I need to find the firt occurence of the quotes after "opts.attribute" and replace this with "opts.value".

I have no idea how to do it, RegExp a my personal nightmare :-/

Comment: Regex with non-regular data is a nightmare indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var oldclass="atestclass {action : '/myurl/param1/param2'}";
var regExp = new RegExp("(\\{\\s*"+opts.attribute+"\\s*:\\s*').*?'", 'igm');
var newclass = oldclass.replace(regExp, "$1"+opts.value.replace('$', '$$')+"'");
```